# Entity Framework is very very slow in my project about 2 min for huge amount of data

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ninject

I am developing a project using EF 6. So I have these layers in my project :

1. Database (dbcontext)
2. IRepo
3. Repo
4. UI

I configured my EF in database layer as you can see here:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            Database.SetInitializer(
                new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, MigrationsConfiguration>()
                );
    }

    public DbSet<Line> Lines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Spool> Spools { get; set; }
    /......
}
```

In my `IRepo` I define my interfaces :

```
public interface IEndRepository
{
        IQueryable<End> Get();
        bool Save();
        bool Add(End newValue);
        bool Delete(End deletedValue);
        bool Edit(End UpdatedValue);
        IQueryable<End> FindById(int Id);
}
```

And in repo I implement these interfaces, and in my application (windows form) I inject these repositories to my form using ninject. One of my query looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<ViewMaterial> ViewIMaterial()
{
    return (from i in _ctx.Materials
            join material in _ctx.MaterialDescriptions on i.MaterialDescriptionId equals material.Id
            join Line in _ctx.Lines on i.LineId equals Line.Id
            join user in _ctx.Users on i.UserId equals user.Id
            join sheet in _ctx.Sheets on i.SheetId equals sheet.Id
            select new ViewMaterial
                   {
                      Id = i.Id,
                      LineId = Line.LineNumber,
                      SheetId = sheet.SheetNumber,
                      Discipline = i.Discipline,
                      Quantity = i.Quantity,
                      MaterialDescriptionId = material.ItemCode,
                      SubmitDateTime = i.SubmitDateTime,
                      UserId = user.FullName
                    });
}
```

This query is inside Repo layer, the number of rows in material is 16000, materiaddescription is 42000, line is 1300 and sheet is 3300, user is 1.

When I execute this query the result is generated after 3 minutes, and when it is loaded my application works very slow .

I change the first line of my query to `from i in _ctx.Materials.take(20)` but same problem .

Comment: do you loop over these entries in a foreach loop? call .ToList() before then. Also, if you do not need to do changes to the entries, use .AsNoTracking().

Comment: @DevilSuichiro i don't have any loop in fetching data ,where should i call .tolist ?

Comment: either directly in this function, or whereever you actually execute the query created by this IQueryable.

Comment: When i call my function in UI i have called .tolist for example :datagridview.datasource=myrepo.ViewIMaterial().tolist();

Comment: alright, this should improve performance by quite a bit. How about .AsNoTracking()? I do believe relationship fixup might be quite a hit with ~70k entries.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro i don't know how can i use AsNoTracking()

Comment: .AsNoTracking() is an extension method on IQueryable<T>. You can use it to turn off ChangeTracking (essentially) for the collection.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro in my UI layer i change tolist to AsNoTracking ,but i get conversion error

Comment: you have to use both, .AsNoTracking() will still return an IQueryable.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro i got it let me check it

Comment: @DevilSuichiro i changed it to AsNoTracking.tolist() but still is very slow

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why it's very slow is the multiple "join".
Doing more than 2 "join" in a single request using EF could be fast heavy.

Try to separate the request or change your code to Lazy Load all the data you need right after the query using .Load() for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
public IQueryable<ViewMaterial> ViewIMaterial()
{
    return _ctx.Materials.Take(20)
        .Select(e=> new ViewMaterial
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            LineId = e.Line.LineNumber,
            SheetId = e.Sheet.SheetNumber,
            Discipline = e.Discipline,
            Quantity = e.Quantity,
            MaterialDescriptionId = e.MaterialDescriptions.ItemCode,
            SubmitDateTime = e.SubmitDateTime,
            UserId = e.User.FullName
        });
}
```